# Python BeautifulSoup web-scraping Tripadvisor hotel detail ratings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, tripadvisor

I want to crawl the details of the hotel reviews on tripadvisor. It's like below,

https://www.tripadvisor.jp/Hotel_Review-g294265-d302294-Reviews-or30-Pan_Pacific_Singapore-Singapore.html#REVIEWS

[review details like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqKfX.png)

[web source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rcoo.png)

but I'm having a problem that when I visit the review details div it returns null. The web code is as follows. I am a beginner of beautifulsoup and python,and this is my code and the output. I noticed that the source code is marked [flex] here,is this related to why I can't get the output? What should I do with it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.jp/Hotel_Review-g294265-d302294-Reviews-or30- Pan_Pacific_Singapore-Singapore.html#REVIEWS"
def get_info(link):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.findAll("div", {'class':'YibKl MC R2 Gi z Z BB pBbQr'}):
        name = items.find("a",{'class':'ui_header_link uyyBf'}).text
        rate = items.find("div",{'data-test-target':'review-rating'}).contents
        rate = str(rate).strip('[<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_')
        rate = rate.strip('0"></span>]')
      
        details = items.find("div",{'class':'ZzICe Me f'})
    print("name:",name,"rate:",rate)
if __name__ == '__main__':
get_info(URL)
```

output:
enter code here
name: ちゃつこ rate: 5
name: yamasanotomodati2019 rate: 4
name: タヌキ rate: 5
name: やまと rate: 5
name: Meander13787362980 rate: 5

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, it would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a webdriver and wait for the js to load, youll need to hit the API:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g294265-d302294-Reviews-or50-Pan_Pacific_Singapore-Singapore.html',
    'x-requested-by': 'TNI1625!AI+pfN0SRiV04L99rYJWb3EV3Lgho83AN4Eq19Phd4s8QdnZ/N2d6uIM1359Lgkf3bJ/UTwvsuK+8yuD7DyZ7qCWKFzIlaU/5mRaG5jrjBihsuGEWt/rjyatL0CUoTWpesU8EUcMjChUsJOZQDU9gA9jzW69vaKk6I/ZgSrQFitP',
    'Origin': 'https://www.tripadvisor.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
 
}

json_data = [
    {
        'query': '0eb3cf00f96dd65239a88a6e12769ae1',
        'variables': {
            'interaction': {
                'productInteraction': {
                    'interaction_type': 'CLICK',
                    'site': {
                        'site_name': 'ta',
                        'site_business_unit': 'Hotels',
                        'site_domain': 'www.tripadvisor.com',
                    },
                    'pageview': {
                        'pageview_request_uid': '0ee828c5-49d2-402a-b651-ea090aa3b422',
                        'pageview_attributes': {
                            'location_id': 302294,
                            'geo_id': 294265,
                            'servlet_name': 'Hotel_Review',
                        },
                    },
                    'user': {
                        'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
                        'site_persistent_user_uid': 'web407a.76.105.157.232.18213E2BBC7',
                        'unique_user_identifiers': {
                            'session_id': '6226E0FF3EDE443392DC27D0E321F0D3',
                        },
                    },
                    'search': {},
                    'item_group': {
                        'item_group_collection_key': '0ee828c5-49d2-402a-b651-ea090aa3b422',
                    },
                    'item': {
                        'product_type': 'Hotels',
                        'item_id_type': 'ta-location-id',
                        'item_id': 302294,
                        'item_attributes': {
                            'element_type': 'number',
                            'action_name': 'REVIEW_NAV',
                            'page_number': 6,
                            'offset': 50,
                            'limit': 10,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        'query': 'ea9aad8c98a6b21ee6d510fb765a6522',
        'variables': {
            'locationId': 302294,
            'offset': 50,
            'filters': [
                {
                    'axis': 'LANGUAGE',
                    'selections': [
                        'en',
                    ],
                },
            ],
            'prefs': None,
            'initialPrefs': {},
            'limit': 10,
            'filterCacheKey': 'locationReviewFilters_302294',
            'prefsCacheKey': 'locationReviewPrefs_302294',
            'needKeywords': False,
            'keywordVariant': 'location_keywords_v2_llr_order_30_en',
        },
    },
    {
        'query': 'e47b7de100177531430992d789c646b6',
        'variables': {
            'pageAdsRequestInput': {
                'hotelTravelInfo': {
                    'checkInDate': '2022-07-31',
                    'checkOutDate': '2022-08-01',
                    'defaultDates': True,
                },
                'locationId': 302294,
                'pageType': 'Hotel_Review',
                'browserType': 'UNKNOWN',
                'globalContextUrlParameters': [
                    {
                        'key': 'detailId',
                        'value': '302294',
                    },
                    {
                        'key': 'geoId',
                        'value': '294265',
                    },
                    {
                        'key': 'offset',
                        'value': 'r50',
                    },
                ],
                'userAgentCategory': 'DESKTOP',
            },
        },
    },
]

response = requests.post('https://www.tripadvisor.com/data/graphql/ids', headers=headers, json=json_data)
response.json()[1]['data']['locations'][0]['reviewListPage']['reviews'][0]['text']
```

you can play around with the parameters and/or iterate over the 'reviews' block of the json response
output:

```
'Our Pan-Pacific experience is totally awesome! Special mention to the entire Pacific Club Lounge for helping us with an unforgettable birthday celebration and to the following people~ Jayrick, Krissel, and Ayaka for an over and above service that exceeded our expectations!'
```

You may not need all of the header and json data information. You may also need to generate random strings to keep the request valid. I would suggest using selenium or playwrite.